# How can I suppress the pinentry dialogue box if there is no gpg password?

Tags: gpg, mutt, gpg-agent, pinentry

I'm using (neo)mutt with GPG. I've set my gpg password to empty, but when I attempt to decrypt an incoming email, mutt still presents a `pinentry` dialogue box. If I just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (with no string), the dialogue box will be dismissed, and the email decrypted as expected.

Given that I have no gpg password, how can I suppress the dialogue box?

The following lines are in my `muttrc`:

```
source /usr/share/doc/mutt/samples/gpg.rc
set pgp_use_gpg_agent = yes
set pgp_sign_as = <alpha_numeric_string>
```

`/usr/share/doc/mutt/samples/gpg.rc` is available [here](https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt/blob/ee3fefef018eedc267cc7c73915228176bfa86e2/contrib/gpg.rc), but essentially includes the following lines.

```
set pgp_decode_command="gpg --status-fd=2 %?p?--passphrase-fd 0? --no-verbose --quiet --batch --output - %f"
set pgp_verify_command="gpg --status-fd=2 --no-verbose --quiet --batch --output - --verify %s %f"
set pgp_decrypt_command="gpg --status-fd=2 %?p?--passphrase-fd 0? --no-verbose --quiet --batch --output - %f"
set pgp_sign_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --quiet --output - %?p?--passphrase-fd 0? --armor --detach-sign --textmode %?a?-u %a? %f"
set pgp_clearsign_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --quiet --output - %?p?--passphrase-fd 0? --armor --textmode --clearsign %?a?-u %a? %f"
set pgp_encrypt_only_command="pgpewrap gpg --batch --quiet --no-verbose --output - --encrypt --textmode --armor --always-trust -- -r %r -- %f"
set pgp_encrypt_sign_command="pgpewrap gpg %?p?--passphrase-fd 0? --batch --quiet --no-verbose --textmode --output - --encrypt --sign %?a?-u %a? --armor --always-trust -- -r %r -- %f"
set pgp_import_command="gpg --no-verbose --import %f"
set pgp_export_command="gpg --no-verbose --export --armor %r"
set pgp_verify_key_command="gpg --verbose --batch --fingerprint --check-sigs %r"
set pgp_list_pubring_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --quiet --with-colons --with-fingerprint --with-fingerprint --list-keys %r"
set pgp_list_secring_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --quiet --with-colons --with-fingerprint --with-fingerprint --list-secret-keys %r"
set pgp_good_sign="^\\[GNUPG:\\] GOODSIG"
set pgp_decryption_okay="^\\[GNUPG:\\] DECRYPTION_OKAY"
```

I'm not sure what else is relevant, but `/home/lee/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` contains

```
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-qt
```

I've also tested the following two commands, but both still present the password box.

```
gpg --export-secret-keys
gpg --export-secret-keys --batch --passphrase ''
```

Comment: set pgp_use_gpg_agent hope it helps

Comment: @user327344 As per my question, I already have this set.